# Making vertical list, and putting something between the items

Tags: html, css

The first part of problem is easy:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pq3KM/

```
ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

<ul>
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu2</li>
    <li>menu3</li>
</ul>
```

so far it works OK, but I want something between the items. For example, I want them to look alike:

```
menu1 | menu2 | menu3
```

instead of

```
menu1 menu2 menu3
```

how to do this?

Comment: uses borders: ul li + li { border-left: 1px solid black; }.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:after` pseudo for this, here am using `|` pipe character, which am embedding using `content` property with an `:after` pseudo. And for the last element, am using `last-of-type` to get rid of the pipe. Here you can also add a `background-image` by making the `:after` pseudo an `inline-block` element. You can also [space up](http://jsfiddle.net/Pq3KM/2/)<sup>Demo</sup> the element by turning it into an `inline-block`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pq3KM/1/)

```
ul li:after {
    content: " | ";
}

ul li:last-of-type:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: why not just use the + selector? ul li + li:before { content: " | "; } (haven't test it yet, so you might have a reason for that)

Comment: uh, nice, I hope all nowaday's browsers get on well with it

Comment: @JohnSmith IE8 supports before after, but `last-of-type` will fail, though polyfills are available, but if you don't care about IE than you can safely use this.

Comment: @DoXicK not required :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien true, but it is shorter and more widely supported, example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wf94f/1/

Comment: @DoXicK ya that is good because you are using `:before` and am using `:after`, though +1 for you :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien yeah true. didn't know the 'last of type' selector yet, so learned something new here again, thanks!

Comment: @DoXicK there are many, just try them out else you will end up with class selectors only ;)

Comment: @Mr.Alien ..and write widely supported code... yeah, we don't want that, do we now?! ;-) But it's always nice to learn stuff like this because it will be usable one day

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42879/discussion-between-mr-alien-and-doxick)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by adding a vertical line char before 'li' other than first one.

```
<ul>
   <li>menu1</li>
 | <li>menu2</li>
 | <li>menu3</li>
</ul>
```